# Elasticsearch: how to perform exact match on wildcard field

Tags: elasticsearch, match, wildcard

We used the following query to get exact match on wildcard field:

```
"query_string": {
          "query": "\"abcd\"",
          "fields": [
            "*.Name"
          ]
        }
      }
```

but it returned results also for values, such as: abcde, abcd1, etc...

Does anyone has an idea how to get an exact match in such case? We tried to add "analyzer:simple", which made things worse and sometimes didn't return results at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did the same kind of query but it only gets exact matches on my side! I do have to put the string in between  `*` to get a result that contains the searched string! I'm running elasticsearch-0.90.2 maybe it's something that has been fixed recently?

Comment: Your field, I guess, is not analyzed, therefore you should add '*'. Our field is analyzed and we want to perform the exact match on the stored value and not the analyzed value. And also we don't want to replicate our data to other not analyzed field.

Comment: Ok, might be that. I'm gonna check and let you know if I find sonething that could help.